# How to parse the XML generated from Sharepoint form submission, using java?

Tags: java, sharepoint, jaxb, infopath

I've one requirement in which the the requester will submit the info path form using the sharepoint, How to parse the XML file and extract the values using java? 
Please give the suggestions? 
I tried the below code.

```
 import java.io.File;

 import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;    
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
public class feedToobject {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    File file=new File("C:\\file1.xml");
    try {
        JAXBContext jb=JAXBContext.newInstance(FeedProvisioning.class);
        Unmarshaller um=jb.createUnmarshaller();
        FeedProvisioning feed=(FeedProvisioning) um.unmarshal(file);

        System.out.println(feed.getRequestor_email());
        System.out.println(feed.requestor_email);


    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


}
```

but getting error as 
 " javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2014-05-29T10:32:58", local:"xferRequestFields"). Expected elements are (none)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(Unknown Source)"

My xml file is as below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?mso-infoPathSolution solutionVersion="1.0.0.97" PIVersion="1.0.0.0"                       href="file:///\\s3\4thline\Clients\lpop\Project\Service%20Design\Project%20Transfer%20Request%20Form%203.01.xsn" name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:Project-Transfer-Request-Form-0-5-1:-    myXSD-2014-05-29T10-32-58" productVersion="15.0.0" ?>
    <?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.3"?>     <my:xferRequestFields my:xferArchitectEmail="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2014-05-29T10:32:58" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-us">
   <my:reqName>Sushma</my:reqName>
  <my:reqEmail>sushma@cnk.com</my:reqEmail>
```

Thanks 
sushma.

Comment: show code on what you've tried so far

Comment: That isn't code.  I suggest you nail down the specific error you are getting, try to figure it out as best you can and if that fails then post your exact question according to the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added the code which i tried, erro and xml file in the question itself.

Comment: How did you get your JAXB classes? Check if it has the @XmlRootElement annotation (sometimes it is missing: the parser cannot make sure it is not used externally, but that's a long discussion, just google it). Another thing: check if you have a generated package-info.java file with an annotation specifying the schema. Also check the parsed XML if it has a consistent schema link.

Comment: I'd written JAXB classes, could you please help me which will be @XmlRootElement in my case? Since it is a infopath doc.. The structure is very different.